# How to add a class to enam and how use Description attribute in Razor page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, view, enums

I have enam by type

```
public enum Types
    {
        [Description ("Once")]
        Once = 1,
        [Description ("SpecificDay")]
        SpecificDay = 2,
        [Description ("Daily")]
        Daily = 3,
        [Description ("Weekly")]
        Weekly = 4,
        [Description ("Monthly")]
        Monthly = 5
    }
```

and I need to display this enum it on the page.
the page is displayed in dropdownMenu

```
<ul class = "dropdownmenu" role = "menuRole">
                        <li role = "main" value = "">
                            <a class="active" role="item" tablindex="11" href="#" case="once"> Once </a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li role = "main" value = "">
                            <a class="" role="item" tabindex="11" href="#" case="specificday"> SpecificDay </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role = "main" value = "">
                            <a class="" role="item" tabindex="11" href="#" case="daily"> Daily </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role = "main" value = "">
                            <a class="" role="item" tabindex="11" href="#" case="weekly"> Weekly </a>
                        </li>
                        <li role = "main" value = "">
                            <a class="" role="item" tabindex="1" href="#" case="monthly"> Monthly</a>
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
```

in this  print all enum. From front i get values of this Types and i need  make class=active
like:

```
    Model.Types=Monthly;
    <li role = "main" value = "">
    <a class="**active**" role="item" tabindex="1" href="#" case="monthly"> Monthly</a> 
    </li>
//other without class="**active**"
    <li role = "main" value = "">
    <a class="" role="item" tablindex="11" href="#" case="once"> Once </a>
    </li>
    <li role = "main" value = "">
    <a class="" role="item" tabindex="11" href="#" case="daily"> Daily </a>
    </li>
    <li role = "main" value = "">
    <a class="" role="item" tabindex="11" href="#" case="weekly"> Weekly </a>
    </li>
    <li role = "main" value = "">
    <a class="" role="item" tabindex="1" href="#" case="monthly"> Monthly</a>
    </li>
```

at the first open page (there are no entries in the database and Model=null), the class="active" must be set automatically for once case

i try use

```
@foreach (var val in Enum.GetNames (typeof (Types)))
                        {
                            @if (Model == null || Model.Types.ToString (). Length == 0
                             || val == Types.Once.ToString ()
                             && Model.Type.ToString () == val)
                            {
                                <li role = "main" data-value = "@ val.ToLowerInvariant ()">
                                    <a class="active" role="item" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-case="@val.ToLowerInvariant()"> @ val.ToLowerInvariant () </a>
                                </li>
                            }
                        }
```

but I don’t know how to set the active class for one field and display Description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i make helper

```
public static class EnumHelper
    {
        public static string GetDisplayDescription(this Enum enumValue)
        {
            return enumValue.GetType()
                            .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                            ?.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()
                            ?.Description;
        }
    }
```

use:

```
@EnumHelper.GetDisplayDescription(@Model.Types)
```